# "Applying Setter Injection to an Existing Object " Can I do this?

Tags: structuremap

Two existing objects SetAllProperties () Should I use this?

```
        var theGateway1 = new DefaultGateway();
        var something = new Something();
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>

        {

            x.ForRequestedType<IGateway>().TheDefault.IsThis(theGateway);
            x.ForRequestedType<ISomething>().TheDefault.IsThis(something); 

            // First we create a new Setter Injection Policy that

            // forces StructureMap to inject all public properties

            // where the PropertyType is IGateway

            x.SetAllProperties(y =>

            {

                y.OfType<IGateway>();
                y.OfType<ISomthing>();

            });

        });
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? These two objects injected as Properties or just instances of their types?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to inject all setters with these two instances, it's ok. Just use the new syntax:

```
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IGateway>().Use(theGateway);
            x.For<ISomething>().Use(something);

            x.SetAllProperties(y =>
            {
                y.OfType<IGateway>();
                y.OfType<ISomething>();
            });
        });
```